# Calculator in Swing Java

Tags: java, swing

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
public class calc implements ActionListener
{
    JFrame f;
    JPanel p;
    JTextField jt1,jt2,jt3;
    JButton j1,j2;
    static double a=0,b=0,result=0;
    static int operator=0;

  calc() 
  {
      f = new JFrame();
      p = new JPanel();
      jt1 = new JTextField(20);
      jt2 = new JTextField(20);
      j1 = new JButton("+");
      j2 = new JButton("-");
      jt3 = new JTextField();

      f.add(p);
      p.add(jt1);
      p.add(jt2);
      p.add(j1);
      p.add(j2);
      j1.addActionListener(this);
      j2.addActionListener(this);

      f.setVisible(true);
      f.pack();
      f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  }
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
  {
      if(ae.getSource()=="+")
      {
          a=Double.parseDouble(jt1.getText());
          operator = 1;
          b=Double.parseDouble(jt2.getText());
          switch(operator)
          {
              case 1: result=(a+b);

          }

          jt3.setText(result);

      }
  }
  public static void main(String [] args)
  {
      calc obj = new calc();
  }
}
```

i'm making a calculator using java swing, the output of this code is:

```
calc.java:48 error: incompatible types: double cannot be converted to String 
     jt3.setText(result);
```

i think this is not a big error, well help me to get rid of this, i just want to sum didn't add more functions like multiply or minus or etc, i just want to run as small code first then i'll add more functions to it well help will be appreciated thanks.

Comment: Can you explain which part of the error is not clear to you?

Comment: You're trying to set the text field to a double. Text fields take in a string value. Convert result to a string first then assign it.

Comment: Java has a class `Double` with a static method `toString` which needs a `double` as parametre: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#toString(double)

Comment: Side note:`ae.getSource()=="+"` will not work, use "equals" for strings

Comment: See also this [calculator example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7441804/418556).  It uses `ScriptEngine` to evaluate the expression in the text field.

Answer (score 1):

Easy way is:

```
//jt3.setText(result);
jt3.setText("" + result);
```

This will force the compiler to create a String of the two values.

Comment: thanks it is running but it is not adding two numbers in 3rd textfield, what's problem in this code?

Comment: @AbHiTheNua, so the answer to the original question has been given. Glad it helped. Don't forget to "accept" the answer so people know the problem has been solved.

Comment: `it is not adding two numbers` - is the code being executed. Did you add debug code to the if statement. Did you read the comments about not using "==" for string comparison. If you still have problems, after following all the advice given then post a proper [mcve] in another question. And don't forget to name your class properly. Class names should start with an upper case character.

Answer (score 1):

Use `jt3.setText(String.valueOf(result));`.
`.setText()` only accept String type.
You can see it in [Class TextField](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/TextField.html#setText(java.lang.String)).

Answer (score 1):

**Class text** can accept only string values.
where the result you provided as an argument is **Double**

You can use this to convert it as a string

```
string converted = Double.toString(result);
```

Comment: If you find the answer you wanted, Press the tick mark on the side, or if you have further questions, comment.

Answer (score 0):

This error is because `JTextField` is expecting a `String` to set the text to it, not a `double`, so, you need to either:

```
jt3.setText(String.valueOf(result));
```

Or

```
jt3.setText("" + result);
```

The first one will convert result to a `String` value, while the second one will concatenate an empty `String` to `result`, and return a `String` as well.

However one last suggestion I want you to take note of is, don't use single letter variables, make them more descriptive, for example:

```
JFrame f; //This should be JFrame frame;
```

The same for the `JPanel` and the rest of your variables, since in larger programs it could be hard to remember that `f` means a `JFrame` and not the conversion to Fahrenheit from Celsius or a formula like `F = m * a`, it may be confusing and really hard to debug / understand later on.

And also as has been said in the comments above, use `.equals` to compare String in Java, see [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java) for more on this